# Conditionally navigate on button click

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI Button that should check for a certain condition (isSmiling) - and if this boolean is true - it should navigate to a new view on the NavigationStack - otherwise it should display an alert. Below, I have a NavigationLink in addition to a Button - but I really just want the button to programmatically navigate to a new view when it is a pressed and when isSmiling is set to `true`. I don't want the NavigationLink to be shown. How can I achieve this?

```
struct ControlView: View {
  @Binding var isSmiling: Bool
    
  @State private var showingAlert = false


  var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        NavigationStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Please smile !!! Click button to continue").bold().font(.title3).padding(.bottom).background(.white)
                HStack(spacing: 12) {
                    
                    NavigationLink {
                        WelcomeView()
                    } label: {
                        ZStack {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            Text("Validate").font(.title3)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                    }.frame(width: 100, height: 50).padding(.top, 10)
                    
                    Button("Validate") {
                        print("isSmiling = \(isSmiling)")
                        if !isSmiling {
                            showingAlert = true
                        }
                        
                    }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                        .tint(.blue)
                        .controlSize(.large)
                        .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                            Alert(title: Text("Livliness detection failed"),
                                  message: Text("Please smile!"),
                                  dismissButton: .default(Text("Got it!")))
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of a `NavigationLink` with `destination` use `Button` & `navigationDestination`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Add

```
@Published var path: NavigationPath = .init()
```

2- Define `NavigationStack` like this

```
NavigationStack(path: $path) {

          ....
                    Button("Validate") {
                        print("isSmiling = \(isSmiling)")
                        if isSmiling {
                             path.append(.destinationPage)
                        }
                        else {
                            showingAlert = true
                        }
                        
                    }
                   .navigationDestination(for: Destination.self) { value in
                     WelcomeView()
                   }
          ....
}
```

3- Add this `enum`

```
enum Destination { 
    case destinationPage
}
```

Comment: navigationDestination goes inside the NavigationStack